# does the thunderbolt display have a cooling fan?

Tags: thunderbolt

My recently purchased 27" Thunderbolt display is overheating. Is there an internal fan that should be coming on?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Apple Thunderbolt Display does have a fan.  See: [Apple Thunderbolt Display Teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Apple+Thunderbolt+Display+Teardown/6525)

It's a brushless fan, so it might be rather quite when running at lower speeds.

I have a Thunderbolt Display and I can't recall having heard it as I usually hear the fan from my MacBook Pro above all.

Cropped image from link above:

[image]